# How do you convert an entire directory of flac files to alac and keep the metadata with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

How do I mass convert files from flac to alac without losing the metadata? (windows)

Answer (score -1):

```
FOR %A IN (*.flac) DO ffmpeg -i "%A" -c:a alac "%~nA.m4a"
```